# How to solve package conflict in Centos 6

Tags: centos6, yum, php56

I am trying to upgrade from php 5.5 to 5.6, so far i've managed to upgrade to php5.6, setup suPHP 0.7, and add php-mysql extension.
I used the webtatic repo to install php 5.6
I read on [this page](https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62911&p=265215)  that it is not advised to have webtatic along remi. So i removed the files in /etc/yum.conf.d/ in order to not have webtatic in the list of repo.

However I couldn't install the php-xml for DomDocument, some CMS use it.

I tried :

```
yum install php-xml
```

not working

```
yum --enablerepo remi install php-xml
```

It gives me the message :

```
Résolution des dépendances
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.5.38-7.el6.remi will be installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-7.el6.remi     pour le paquet : php-xml-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.5.38-7.el6.remi will be installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) pour le paquet : php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.5 will be installé
--> Traitement du conflit : php56w-common-5.6.31-2.w6.x86_64 entre en conflit avec php-common < 5.6
--> Résolution des dépendances terminée
Erreur : php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64
Vous pouvez essayer d'utiliser --skip-broken pour contourner le problème
 Vous pouvez essayer d'exécuter : rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried the --skip-broken parameter but i receive:

```
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.5.38-7.el6.remi will be installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-7.el6.remi pour le paquet : php-xml-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.5.38-7.el6.remi will be installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) pour le paquet : php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.5 will be installé
--> Traitement du conflit : php56w-common-5.6.31-2.w6.x86_64 entre en conflit avec php-common < 5.6

Paquets omis en raison de problèmes de dépendances :
php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 depuis remi-php55
php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 depuis remi-php55
php-xml-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 depuis remi-php55
```

Then I tried rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest, and then again the previous command, but still can't solve the problem.
Thank you for any help !

UPDATE:
I manage to get the owner of the remi repository https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/, there is a configurator, I chose the version of php, and it laid out the steps to achieve what you want, but unfortunately i had this message :

```
Erreur du contrôle de transaction :
file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0 from install of mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package compat-mysql51-5.1.54-1.el6.remi.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0 from install of mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.38-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package compat-mysql51-5.1.54-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

I am trying to solve this issue now in their forum.

Comment: Migrate to Debian!  (But seriously, RPM Hell is why I left Mandrake for Debian...)

Comment: @RonJohn unfortunately it is a legacy install in my company,personally i'd choose Debian as well

Comment: my apologies for the poor attempt at humor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am having a little trouble with the language barrier, but I think enough of it makes sense along with your description in English.

I think you need to remove the packages that were installed with webtatic, not just remove the repo. Specifically, it looks like php56w-common is from that repo and is the source of your trouble. You'll want to install PHP 5.6 from remi-php56 and stick to one 3rd party ecosystem.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the output was in French.. Do i need to revert to php 5.5? OMG it was hard enough to upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6.

Comment: The reason I used Webtatic i because when i wanted to install remi-php56, it says no remi-php56 available.

Comment: I think this answer is right; try "yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 install php56".  If I'm reading correctly, the repository is "remi-php56" not the package.

Comment: See the Wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: @YvonHuynh That wizard is what you need. (Commented by the author no less!) The package name is just 'php' in the 'remi-php56' repository. It updates the system php package.

Comment: @AaronCopley thanks for the tip, i managed to get to php5.6 finally !  with /usr/bin/yum install php